# How can I remove Achievements from Game Center which I added for testing purpose?

Tags: ios, game-center, achievements

I'm new to Apple's Game Center and while I'm studying it I added some of Achievements.

It seems that if the App is go on live, Apple don't let us remove Achievements data from Game Center. But before uploading App to App Store, is it possible to delete Achievements which is added for testing purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

according to itunes connect  "Once an achievement has gone live for any version of your app, it cannot be removed." but I think you can still modify it to an usable achievement. or just hide it so player won't see it. can you?